# how to inject line feeds into dynamically created html (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating HTML from javascript code.

What character(s)/escape codes should I add to the long html to cut the html into smaller lines (in the html source level, not in the rendered html result)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `\n` for unix/linux or `\n\r` for Windows.

**Example:**

```
var someString = 'Hello ' + 'Wordl\n';
someString += 'Hello ' + 'Wordl Again\n';
```

Comment: strangely when I add \n between two images who are supposed to be positioned one next to the other without space it adds a space.
for example:
<a href='' style='border:none; text-decoration:none;' ><img style='border:none; margin:0 0 0 0; padding;0 0 0 0;' src='image'/></a>

Positions the images without gaps.
But 
<a href='' style='border:none; text-decoration:none;' >\n<img style='border:none; margin:0 0 0 0; padding;0 0 0 0;' src='image'/>\n</a> 
Adds a gap between the images.
Is it possible to add line break in the source code without adding a gap in the rendered html? (tested on firefox).